# How to use sendAudio in Telegram bot (Python)

Tags: python, json, mp3, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a Telegram bot, it replies with text and images, but I have a problem with sending an MP3 file in the reply. Can anyone please help?

This part of code defines the reply:

```
        def reply(msg=None, img=None, aud=None):
        if msg:
            resp = urllib2.urlopen(BASE_URL + 'sendMessage', urllib.urlencode({
                'chat_id': str(chat_id),
                'text': msg.encode('utf-8'),
                'disable_web_page_preview': 'false',
                # 'reply_to_message_id': str(message_id),
                'reply_markup': json_keyboard,
            })).read()
        elif img:
            resp = multipart.post_multipart(BASE_URL + 'sendPhoto', [
                ('chat_id', str(chat_id)),
                ('reply_to_message_id', str(message_id)),
            ], [
                ('photo', 'image.jpg', img),
            ])
        elif aud:
            resp = multipart.post_multipart(BASE_URL + 'sendAudio', [
                ('chat_id', str(chat_id)),
                ('reply_to_message_id', str(message_id)),
            ], [
                ('audio', 'aud.mp3', aud),
            ])
        else:
            logging.error('no msg or img specified')
            resp = None
```

And this one defines the type of message it should return:

```
       elif 'Two' in text:
        img = Image.open('statimg/firstf.jpg')
        output = StringIO.StringIO()
        img.save(output, 'JPEG')
        reply(img=output.getvalue())
    elif 'Three' in text:
        aud = open('statimg/firsta.mp3')
        output = StringIO.StringIO()
        aud.save(output, 'MP3')
        reply(aud=output.getvalue())
    elif 'One' in text:
        # json_keyboard = json.dumps({keym: [bline3]})
        bline1 = [b1]
        bline2 = [b2]
        json_keyboard = json.dumps({keym: [bline1, bline2]})
        if func6.state == 0:
            reply('Hello text1')
            func6()
        elif func6.state == 1:
            func6()
            reply('Hello text2')
```

For "One" and "Two" in text ot works perfectly (returns text for "One" and image for "Two"), but for "Three" it doesn't return an mp3 file.

What could be the problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply solved the issue this way:

```
        elif aud:
            resp = multipart.post_multipart(BASE_URL + 'sendAudio', [
                ('chat_id', str(chat_id)),
                #('caption', 'Music in the park'),
                ('reply_markup', json_keyboard),
            ], [
                ('audio', 'Play', aud),
            ])

reply(aud=urllib.urlopen('statimg/musone.mp3').read())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with `output = StringIO.StringIO()`

you should use 
`io.BytesIO()`

Here is a working code I am using:

```
def sendTelegramAudio(self, file_url, text):
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/botxxx:yyyy/sendAudio";
    remote_file = requests.get(file_url)
    file1 = io.BytesIO(remote_file.content)
    file1.name = 'audio.mp3'
    files = {'audio': file1}
    data = {'chat_id' : "@your_channel", 'caption':text}
    r= requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
    print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any chance to use this io.BytesIO approach without using requests.get()? To transfer the data via multipart.post_multipart()?